# How to get PowerShell to execute all lines in the script? (and not take a rest on dotnet?)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a PowerShell version 5.1.19041.610 script that does roughly the following

```
Do Command 1

Do Command 2

dotnet run "..\MyApiProject\API.csproj" --no-build

Do Command 4
```

It works fine until `dotnet run` hijacks the session and outputs:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

The script just stops there. I need it to Do Command 4. How can I get PowerShell to start dotnet and just carry on to the next command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to prevent the *synchronous* `dotnet run ...` command from blocking your script.

- Asynchronously launch the `dotnet run ...` command in a *new window* (works on Windows only), using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

```
Start-Process dotnet 'run "..\MyApiProject\API.csproj" --no-build'
```

- Run the `dotnet run ...` command invisibly in a *background job*, using [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job):<sup>[1]</sup>

```
Start-Job { $using:PWD | Set-Location; dotnet run ..\MyApiProject\API.csproj --no-build }
```

- Note that [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now offers a more convenient way to create background jobs, similar to POSIX-compatible shells, via `&`, the [background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#background-operator-):

  - `dotnet run ..\MyApiProject\API.csproj --no-build &`
  - Also, a more light-weight option is to use a *thread* job instead of a (child process-based) background job (the `ThreadJob` module that provides the [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet comes with PowerShell (Core) 7+, but can also be installed in Windows PowerShell)

    - `Start-ThreadJob { dotnet run ..\MyApiProject\API.csproj --no-build }`

---

<sup>[1] See the conceptual [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) topic for information on how to *manage* jobs. Note that using `$using:PWD | Set-Location` is needed in *Windows PowerShell* to ensure that the background job uses the same current location as the caller; in PowerShell (Core) 7+ this is no longer necessary, because the caller's location is automatically inherited.</sup>